# Pandas skipping malformed line in csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file with pandas. the file is very long and malformed in the middle like so

```
Date,Received Date,Tkr,Theta,Wid,Per
2007-08-03,2017/02/13 05:30:G,F,B,A,1
2007-08-06,2017/02/13 05:30:G,F,A,B,1
2007-08-07,2017/02/13 05:30:G,F,A,B,1
2007-08-,nan,,,,
2000-05-30 00:00:00,2017/02/14 05:30:F,D,10,1,1
2000-05-31 00:00:00,2017/02/14 05:30:F,D,10,1,1
```

My line which is failing is this:

```
full_frame = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=["Date"],error_bad_lines=False).set_index("Date").sort_index()[:date]
```

with the error

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > datetime.datetime()
   File "/A/B/C.py", line 236, in load_ex
    full_frame = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=["Date"],error_bad_lines=False).set_index("Date").sort_index()[:date]
```

`date` is just a variable that holds a given input date.

This is happening because of the broken line in the middle. I have tried to do

`error_bad_line=False` but that wont prevent my script from failing.

When i take out the bad line from my csv and run it, it works fine. This csv will be used as an input and I cant modify it at source so I was wondering if there is a way to skip a line based on length of the line in the csv in pandas or something else I can do to make it work without duplicating/modifyng the file

UPDATE

The bad line is stored in my data frame if i simply do a

```
read_csv
```

as `2007-08-           NaN    NaN   NaN      NaN     NaN`

UPDATE 2:

if i try to just do

```
full_frame = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=["Date"],error_bad_lines=False)
full_frame = full_frame.dropna(how="any")
# this drops the NaN row for sure
full_frame = full_frame.set_index("Date").sort_index()[:date]
```

still gives same error :(

Comment: I was able to copy and paste your sample data into a csv file and read it just fine with pandas. Try to clean up your code, it looks like you're doing too much all at once. Read the data in first before trying to parse any dates and such. All I have is `df = pd.read_csv("test.dat")` and it read everything just fine.

Comment: Actually, I didn't read the part about the dates. This is an easy fix if you read in the file, then clean the separators using string operations or regex. I'll add some code to this after my morning meetings.

Comment: code would be much appreciated, never used pandas before :)

Comment: `2017/02/13 05:30:G` what time format is that? What is G?

Comment: that is just mili seconds like 000111213

Answer (score 2):

So I gave this a quick shot. Your data has inconsistencies which should may be of concern to you for your analysis, and you should investigate. Analysis is only as good as that data quality is.

Here's some code (not the best, but gets the job mostly done)

First, since your data needs some work, I read it in as raw text. Then I write a function to parse the dates. I collect the columns in one list, and the rest of the data in another.

For all the data that needs to have dates, I loop over the data 1 line at a time and pass it through parse_dates.

`parse_dates` works by reading in a list, grabbing the first item in the list (the date part) then trying to convert it from a simple string to a date. Since not all are datetime, I only grab the first 10 bytes for just dates.

Once I have a cleaner data, I pass it through `pandas` and obtain a dataframe. Then I set the date to the index. This could be improved upon but given that this is not my job, I'll let you do the rest.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


rawdata = []
with open("test.dat", "r") as stuff:
    for line in stuff:
        line1 = line[:-1]
        rawdata.append(line1.split(","))

def parse_dates(line):
    datepart = line[0][:10] ## get the date-time, and for the date-time, only get the date part
    ## since not all rows have date + time, cut it down to date
    try:
        result = dt.datetime.strptime(datepart, "%Y-%m-%d") ## try converting to date
    except ValueError:
        result = None
    line[0] = result ## update
    return line



cols = rawdata[0]
data = rawdata[1:]

print data

data = [parse_dates(line) for line in data]

print data

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = cols)
print df
df.index = df['Date']
```

Also, a simple Google search shows plenty of ways of handling dates with Python+pandas. Here is one link I found:
https://chrisalbon.com/python/strings_to_datetime.html

Comment: I'm getting a key error when I try to do [:date] to match my code. But thank you so much!

Comment: Well if "Date" is your index, then sort by index. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html

Comment: Or, before you set "Date" to the index, sort it by "Date" then set it to index using sort_values http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: So i did all that, but it is giving me a different error now, I am guessing there is no way to not read the empty file in the first place?

Comment: No, it may be an issue you're overlooking. That line is pretty trivial.

Comment: The issue is that when I do it the list way, i think it treats everything as a string and then further down in my code it breaks a few things.